# Is there anyway to display who created pod or modified in kubernetes in logs?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubectl, amazon-eks, cicd

Is there anyway to configure pod  logging in Kubernetes in order to see who has created/modified it and that should visible in logs?

I tried over internet but not found answers!

Answer (score 3):

A cluster audit policy is needed to monitor activity in your cluster. It audits user activities, applications that use Kubernetes APIs, and the control plane itself.

The Audit Policy defines which events need to be logged and what data should be logged for each event.

You can either write these logs to a file path or create a webhook to send these events to an external HTTP API.

In your case, this policy should be sufficient.

```
apiVersion: audit.k8s.io/v1
kind: Policy
rules:
  - level: Metadata
    resources:
    - group: ""
      resources: ["pods"]
```

You can specify the level as "Request" or "RequestResponse", if you want to capture more data for each event.

You can refer to this [step-by-step tutorial](https://arabitnetwork.com/2021/03/13/k8s-enabling-auditing-logs-step-by-step/) to apply this policy to your cluster.

For more information, please check these docs - [K8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/audit/)

Comment: It should be on eks cluster

Comment: Is the cluster deployed on fargate?

Comment: no its not deployed on fargate and i am unable to see that api-server deployment on eks cluster 
i was following that video which you send

Comment: Found this on aws docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/control-plane-logs.html . Not sure if you've already tried this.

Comment: tried but it doesn't show who create that or deleted that its not showing user or username is there any way which we can do with out that above link